# What does this mean in Ruby language?

Tags: ruby, splat

Run the following code,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
head, *tail = a
p head
p tail
```

You will get the result

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Who can help me to explain the statement `head,*tail = a`, Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`head, *tail = a` means to assign the first element of the array `a` to `head`, and assign the rest of the elements to `tail`.

`*`, sometimes called the "splat operator," does a number of things with arrays. When it's on the left side of an assignment operator (`=`), as in your example, it just means "take everything left over."

If you omitted the splat in that code, it would do this instead:

```
head, tail = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p head # => 1
p tail # => 2
```

But when you add the splat to `tail` it means "Everything that didn't get assigned to the previous variables (`head`), assign to `tail`."

Comment: nice answer! :) but you really should change your profile pic, you look like an overly groomed poodle ;) hehe

Comment: Haha. I haven't got that one before. I'll take it under advisement. :)

Comment: @banister: His current pic (maybe not the same one used back then) makes him look like Justin Bieber!

Answer (score 8):

First, it is a parallel assignment. In ruby you can write

```
a,b = 1,2
```

and a will be 1 and b will be 2. You can also use

```
a,b = b,a
```

to swap values (without the typical temp-variable needed in other languages).

The star * is the pack/unpack operator. Writing

```
a,b = [1,2,3]
```

would assign 1 to a and 2 to b. By using the star, the values 2,3 are packed into an array and assigned to b:

```
a,*b = [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby at all, but my guess is that the statement is splitting the list `a` into a head (first element) and the rest (another list), assigning the new values to the variables `head` and `tail`.

This mechanism is usually referred (at least in Erlang) as [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching).